# Can't find description of methods in HotChocolate.AspNetCore

Tags: asp.net-core, hotchocolate

I installed HotChocolate.AspNetCore package (v. 11.0.9) for my project via NuGet in Visual Studio. While writing methods names or hovering on them I can't see what these methods actually do. I went to some classes to check if there were any summary tags but I didn't see anything. So my question is: does this graphql package have any description of methods at all and if so, how can I "install" it?

Answer (score 1):

It does and we are constantly putting more in there. Can you give an example where you are missing summary tags? Best file an issue for this on our GitHub repro so we can track and fix those.

https://github.com/ChilliCream/hotchocolate

Comment: In this short term, I managed to use only a small part of these methods, and here are some of them: service extensions methods (AddGraphQLServer, AddQueryType, AddMutationType), endpoint extensions method MapGraphQL and methods of descriptor object (Field, Type, Description, Argument etc.). All of them work pretty fine but it would be easier to write code with description :)

Comment: Still file an issue for the once that are missing things, we will track and fix things like that.